# React не видит значение

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, create-react-app

Я подключил к своему коду CRA(create-react-app), что бы разбить приложение на модули, но за ними пошли первые проблемы. Сегодня хочу её решить , есть код -

```
import React  from 'react';
import TitleName from './components/TitleName';
import TodoForm from './components/TodoForm';
import TodoTask from './components/TodoTask';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          tasksArray: [],
          value: '',
          key: null,
          crossout: false
      }
      this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
      this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
      this.completeClick = this.completeClick.bind(this);
      this.editClick = this.editClick.bind(this);
  }

  editClick(e) {
      const id = e.target.id;
      let copyObj = Object.assign([], this.state.tasksArray);
      const promptResult = prompt("Edit text", '');
      let result = this.state.tasksArray.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
      if(!promptResult) return;
      copyObj[result].value = promptResult;
      this.setState({ tasksArray: copyObj });
  }

  completeClick(e) {
      const id = e.target.id;  
      let copyObj = Object.assign([], this.state.tasksArray);
      let result = this.state.tasksArray.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
      copyObj[result].crossout = !copyObj[result].crossout;
      this.setState({ tasksArray: copyObj }); 
  }

  onChange(e) {
      this.setState({
          value: e.target.value
      });  
  }

  onSubmit(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      if(!this.state.value) return;
      const newItem = {
          value: this.state.value,
          id: this.state.tasksArray.length,
          key: Date.now(),
          crossout: false
      };
      this.setState(e => ({
          tasksArray: e.tasksArray.concat(newItem),
          value: ''
      }));
  }

  render() {
      return (
          <React.Fragment>
              <TitleName/>
              <TodoForm onSubmit={this.onSubmit} value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onChange}/>
              <TodoTask tasks={this.state.tasksArray} completeClick={this.completeClick} editClick={this.editClick}/>  
          </React.Fragment>          
      );
  }
}


export default App;
```

React выдает ошибку при нажатии на кнопку, мол не видит свойство crossout в 27 строчке, выдает только при манипуляции с кнопкой , это очевидно. Вот у меня есть расписанный код этого фрагмента - 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот картинка ошибки -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Функция манипулирует с модулем TodoTask, вот его код -

```
import React from 'react';

export default class TodoTask extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const tasksNoCrossout = this.props.tasks.map((currentValue) => {
            if(currentValue.crossout){
                return (
                    <li className="list-group-item" key={currentValue.key}>
                        <h1><s className="grey">{currentValue.value}</s></h1>
                        <button id={currentValue.id} onClick={this.props.completeClick} className="buttonRight btn btn-warning mx-3 my-2">Uncomplete</button>
                        <button id={currentValue.id} onClick={this.props.editClick} className="buttonRight btn btn-primary mx-3 my-2">Edit</button>
                    </li>  
                ); 
            }
        });
        const tasksCrossout = this.props.tasks.map((currentValue) => {
            if(!currentValue.crossout){
                return (
                    <li className="list-group-item" key={currentValue.key}>
                        <h1>{currentValue.value}</h1>
                        <button id={currentValue.id} onClick={this.props.completeClick} className="buttonRight btn btn-success mx-3 my-2">Complete</button>
                        <button id={currentValue.id} onClick={this.props.editClick} className="buttonRight btn btn-primary mx-3 my-2">Edit</button>
                    </li>  
                ); 
            }
        });

        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="text-center">Не выполненные</h1>
                <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {tasksCrossout}
                </ul>  
                <h1 className="text-center">Выполненные</h1>
                <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                    {tasksNoCrossout}
                </ul>   
            </div>

        );
      }
  }
```

У меня было пару догадок, но они увенчались провалом. Буду рад любой помощи, заранее спасибо!

Comment: А что мешает открыть отладчик, включить остановку на обработанных исключениях, после чего нажать кнопку и посмотреть, что там происходит. Подозреваю что у тебя в `result` лежит `-1`.

Comment: @Qwertiy да , так и есть. Извиняюсь за потраченное время, только что хотел объявлять вопрос завершенным. Уже все исправил, там была проблема с сравнением(строгим)